# The purpose of second square brackets in this PHP code

Tags: php

Is there a basic explanation or resource about what the second square brackets - [$i] - does in this if statement on the third line?

And while I'm here.. What does the greater than or equal to mean in the array function? Its intention is to create an array if any of four checkboxes are selected.

```
$passtime = array("beachwalks"=>0,"gardening"=>0,"playingsports" =>0,"other"=>0);
for($i=0; $i < count($pastime); $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST["pastime"][$i])) {
        $pastime[$_POST["pastime"][$i]] = 1;
```

Comment: It's an array index. `$_POST['pastime']` is an array.

Comment: It's not greater-than-or-equal, that would be `>=`. `=>` is for defining associations in an associative array.

Comment: its for multidimension array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, $_POST['pastime'] is an array something like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => beachwalks 
  [1] => gardeningArray
  ...
)
```

So, with `$pastime[$_POST["pastime"][$i]]` You are get the value of specified index `0` or `1` and so on.. using `[$i]`

And `=>` is used for defining key-value pairs in an array. So, in your case `[beachwalks]` is a key and [0] is a value

See doc for more info on [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has raised another question though. How does it loop through the array using $i - which is an INT - in this case when it is an associative array and the key is actually a string - e.g. beachwalks (which has the value 0)?

Comment: @Louiee that's because PHP by nature is loosely typed language. PHP does not require explicit type definition in variable declaration. So, a variable holding an INT value can changed to hold a string or boolean value. For ex:- if you have a string `1` and an INT `1` and you add both then you will get the output as `2`. More on this: [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)  [Strict vs. Loose Comparisons in PHP](https://www.copterlabs.com/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

`[$i]` is an array index. The form probably has something like this:

```
What activities do you enjoy?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pastime[0]" value="beachwalks"> Beachwalks<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pastime[1]" value="gardening"> Gardening<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pastime[2]" value="playingsports"> Playing Sports<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pastime[3]" value="other"> Other
```

This will make `$_POST["pastime"]` be an array with elements for all the selected checkboxes, and the value of each element is the value attribute from the HTML. The loop then sets the corresponding elements of the `$pastime` array to `1`.

`=>` is for assigning elements of an associative array. You should be able to find this explained fully in the section on arrays in a PHP tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has raised another question though. How does it loop through the array using $i - which is an INT - in this case when it is an associative array and the key is actually a string - e.g. beachwalks (which has the value 0)?

Comment: PHP will automatically convert integers to strings in this situation.

Comment: Try it: `$array = ["0" => "abc"]; echo $array[0];`